# What does my destructor need to be in this function?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, lexer

My program executes fine, except at the end, when I debug it, it's getting a segmentation error after calling my destructor. I'm not sure what the cause of the issue is. I've posted 2 of the relevant files.

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at Prog3.cc:12

12        cout << "Program executed" << endl;

(gdb) s

Program executed

~Lex (this=0x80375c4) at lex.cc:36

36      delete [] str;

(gdb) s

37      }

(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xfef49418 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string () from /usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) Quit
```

lex.h is below:

```
#ifndef LEX_H
#define LEX_H
#include "token.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
class Lex {
 public:
  Lex(istream& in, string fileName);
  //Lex();
  //Lex(const Lex& l);
  ~Lex();

  static const int INTLIT = 1;  
  static const int FLOATLIT = 2;
  static const int STRLIT = 3;
  static const int IDENT = 4;
  static const int PLUS = 5;
  static const int MINUS = 6;
  static const int TIMES = 7;
  static const int DIVIDE = 8;
  static const int REM = 9;
  static const int ASSIGN = 10;
  static const int LPAREN = 11;
  static const int RPAREN = 12;
  static const int COMMA = 13;
  static const int EQ = 14;
  static const int LT = 15;
  static const int LE = 16;
  static const int GT = 17;
  static const int GE = 18;
  static const int NE = 19;
  static const int SET = 20;
  static const int PRINT = 21;
  static const int WHILE = 22;
  static const int DO = 23;
  static const int END = 24;
  static const int AND = 25;
  static const int OR = 26;
  static const int IF = 27;
  static const int THEN = 28;
  static const int ELSE = 29;
  static const int ENDIF = 30;
  static const int PROGRAM = 31;
  static const int ENDOFFILE = 32;
  static const int ERROR = 33;    
  int charIndex;
  int lineIndex;
  int spaceIndex;
  int lineNum;
  int lineLength[100];
  char ch;
  bool hashCheck;  
  bool stopLoop;
  Token nextToken();  
  char nextChar();    
  char str[256][256];
  bool checkSet;
  void printLex();
  string idents[256];
  int identCount;  
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Token& t);
};
#endif
#include "lex.h"
#include "token.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

lex.cc is here.

```
Lex::Lex(istream& in, string fileName) {   
  stopLoop = false;
  charIndex = 0;
  lineIndex = 0;
  identCount = 0;
  lineNum = 0;  
  hashCheck = false;
  checkSet = false;  
  int tempSize;
  ifstream file;   
  string temp;  
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    lineLength[i] = 0;
  if (!file.is_open()) { file.open(fileName.c_str()); }    
  while(!file.eof()) {  

    std::getline(file,temp);        
    tempSize = temp.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; ++i) {      
      str[lineNum][i] = temp[i];
      lineLength[lineNum] += 1;
    }   
    lineNum++;
  }
  file.close();   
}
Lex::~Lex() { 
delete [] str;
}
void Lex::printLex() {    
  charIndex = 0;
  lineIndex = 0;  
  while (stopLoop == false) {  
    cout << nextToken();
    // cout << "Line index: " << lineIndex << endl;
  }  
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Token& t) {
  out << t.type() << " \t " << t.lexeme() << " \t \t " << (t.line() + 1) << " \t \t " << t.pos() << endl;
  return out;
}
bool isReal(char ch) {
  string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890(){}<>+-/=!*,%&|.";
  if (alphabet.find(ch) != alphabet.npos) return true;
  else return false;
}
bool isNum(char ch) { 
  string specialChars = "1234567890.";
  if (specialChars.find(ch) != specialChars.npos) return true;
  else return false;
}
bool isNumFinal(string b) {
  int length = b.length();
  const char* temp = b.c_str();
  bool henry = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (henry == false) { break; }
    henry = isNum(temp[i]);  
  }
  return henry;
}

bool isSpecialChar(char ch) {
  string specialChars = "(){}<>+-/=!*,%&|";
  if (specialChars.find(ch) != specialChars.npos) return true;
  else return false;
}

char Lex::nextChar() {   
    if (lineIndex >= lineNum) { 
      // cout << "End of file reached\n";
      stopLoop = true;
      return '#';
    }       
    else if (charIndex >= lineLength[lineIndex]) {      
      lineIndex++;
      charIndex = 0;
      return nextChar();
    }   
    else if (str[lineIndex][charIndex] == '#') {      
      hashCheck = true;  
      while (hashCheck = true) {
        if (str[lineIndex][charIndex] == '#') { hashCheck = false; }        
        charIndex++;
        if (charIndex > lineLength[lineIndex]) {
          charIndex = 0;
          lineIndex++;
        }
      }
    }    
    else {
      ch = str[lineIndex][charIndex];
      charIndex++;
      return ch;            
    }   
    cout << "you shouldn't be here\n";
  return str[lineIndex][charIndex];
}

Token Lex::nextToken() { 
  if (charIndex == lineIndex && charIndex == 0) { ch = nextChar(); }        
  while (ch == ' ') { ch = nextChar(); }
  // cout << "CI: " << charIndex << endl;
  string build;
  int tempCharIndex = charIndex;  
  int tempLineIndex = lineIndex;
  build += ch;
  if (charIndex == lineIndex && charIndex == 0) { build = ""; }
  if (checkSet == true) {
    checkSet = false;   
    while (ch != ' ' && tempLineIndex == lineIndex) {
      ch = nextChar();
      if (ch != ' ' && tempLineIndex == lineIndex) 
        build += ch;        
    }
    idents[identCount] = build;
    identCount++;   
    return Token(IDENT, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
  }  
  else if (isSpecialChar(ch)) {    
    switch(ch) {
    case '(':
      ch = nextChar();
      return Token(LPAREN, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case ')':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(RPAREN, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '{':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(THEN, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '}':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(ENDIF, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '+':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(PLUS, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '-':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(MINUS, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '/':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(DIVIDE, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '*':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(TIMES, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '=':
      ch = nextChar();
      if (ch == '=') {      
        build += ch;
        ch = nextChar();        
        return Token(EQ, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
      }
      else {

        return Token(ASSIGN, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
      }
    case '>':
      ch = nextChar();
      if (ch == '=') {      
        build += ch;
        ch = nextChar();
        return Token(GE, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
      }
      else return Token(GT, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '<':
      ch = nextChar();
      if (ch == '=') {                
        build += ch;
        ch = nextChar();
        return Token(LE, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
      }
      else return Token(LT, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '!':
      ch = nextChar();
      if (ch == '=') {      
        build += ch;
        ch = nextChar();
        return Token(NE, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
      }
      else return Token(ERROR, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '%':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(REM, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '&':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(AND, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    case '|':
    ch = nextChar();
      return Token(OR, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    default:
      return Token(ERROR, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    }
  }
  else if (isNum(ch)) {
    tempCharIndex = charIndex;
    while (ch != ' ' && tempLineIndex == lineIndex) {
      ch = nextChar();
      if (isSpecialChar(ch)) { 
        break;
      }
      if (ch != ' ' && tempLineIndex == lineIndex) 
        build += ch;      
    }   
    if (isNumFinal(build)) {
      if (build.find('.') != build.npos) 
        return Token(FLOATLIT, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
      else return Token(INTLIT, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    }
    else return Token(ERROR, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
  }
  else {
    tempCharIndex = charIndex;
    while (ch != ' ' && tempLineIndex == lineIndex) {     
      ch = nextChar(); 
      // cout << "ch: " << ch << endl;
      if (ch != ' ' && tempLineIndex == lineIndex) 
        //cout << "inserted: " << ch << endl;
        build += ch;
    }   
    if (build.compare("while") == 0)
      return Token(WHILE, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    else if (build.compare("if") == 0)
      return Token(IF, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    else if (build.compare("print") == 0)
      return Token(PRINT, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex); 
    else if (build.compare("end") == 0)
      return Token(ENDOFFILE, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    else if (build.compare("else") == 0)
      return Token(ELSE, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    else if (build.compare("do") == 0)  { return Token(DO, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex); }
    else if (build.compare("set") == 0) {
      checkSet = true;
      // cout << "CI: " << str[lineIndex] << endl;
      return Token(SET, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    }   
    else {
      for (int i = 0; i < identCount; ++i) {
        if (build.compare(idents[i]) == 0) { return Token(IDENT, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex); }
      }
      cout << "build:" << build << ".\n"; 
      return Token(STRLIT, build, tempLineIndex, tempCharIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you pass `-Wall` to your `g++` compiler, or did you enable all warnings at compilation?

Comment: Do you expect us to debug this wall of code for you? This is not that kind of site.

Answer (score 8):

Don't call `delete[]` unless you called `new[]`.  `str` is a statically sized array in your class, you need neither `new[]` nor `delete[]` for it.

Your class consists entirely of objects which will either handle their own cleanup, or need no cleanup, so your destructor can simply be empty.  Don't even declare it, and the compiler will provide the correct destructor for you in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`str` does not have dynamic storage duration but you are trying to delete it in the destructor. Remove `delete[] str` from your destructor.

You also are not doing any bounds checking when you fill `str`. This may cause you to overwrite other member variables causing additional problems and is likely the cause of the fault you are experiencing.

```
// tempSize and/or lineNum may be greater than 256
for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; ++i) {      
  str[lineNum][i] = temp[i];
  lineLength[lineNum] += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
Lex::~Lex() { 
 delete [] str;
}
```

in your code, but `str` is not heap allocated. It is a data member of your `Lex` class

I believe a recent GCC invoked as `g++ -Wall -g` would probably have warned you about that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Well, cause you don't need to delete the str array at all, it's not created by you using `new` so you don't need to call `delete`.

VS gives me :
warning C4154: deletion of an array expression; conversion to pointer supplied